# Where can I view a proposal's source code changes?

Tags: governance, voting

It is incredibly important that the source code changes see as many eyes as possible. Where will the proposed changes be visible? Will there be a special branch convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the responsibility of those that are proposing the changes to provide the amended source code - we can then validate the changes with the proposal hash. I assume Nomadic Labs will provide this around when they formally propose the changes.